# Определеяемое и определяющее в синтагме

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Обозначим определяемое и определяющее через Т и Т’ соответственно. Тогда синтагма имеет формулу ТТ’ либо Т’Т.

Почему при-город — это ТТ’, ведь тут характеризуется город (вернее, его часть), который находится рядом с чем-то — при-?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пригород-ТТ’

Пригород - это не город, а  местность **при городе**, то, что находится **при** городе. Определение даётся через город, значит, **город** - определяющее понятие, а определяемое, главное - **при**.

Когда-то пригородом называлась небольшая местность, сейчас это значение устарело, а вот когда оно существовало, можно было сказать "пригород - это несамостоятельный маленький город". Тогда **город** был бы определяемым, главным понятием по отношению к **при**.